# Assign multiple columns from lapply() using dplyr and tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a case in which I'd like to enhance the code to be more straight, assigning multiple elements of `lapply`'s results as columns for `tibble`.

I know how do this for `data.table`, the operation would be like this:

```
data <- data.table(x = 1:9)
data[,  c("y","z") := lapply(2:3, function(p) x ^ p)]

#   x  y   z
#1: 1  1   1
#2: 2  4   8
#3: 3  9  27
#4: 4 16  64
#5: 5 25 125
```

Now, I'd like to do the same with `dplyr`. I have already tried alternatives, for example:

```
data <- tibble(x = 1:9)
data <- data %>% 
            mutate(c("y","z") = lapply(2:3, function(p) x ^ p))
```

but it goes wrong.

Comment: I'm out of the loop, lapply doesnt magically optimize if used within data table or dplyr? `as.data.table(c(data, lapply(c(y = 2, z = 3), function(p) data$x^p)))`

Comment: "optimize the code" in what way? Base R and data.table are your best bet for optimising for speed.

Comment: In the spirit of code golf, the `data.table` solution would be `data[, c("y", "z"):=lapply(2:3, "^", x)]`

Comment: @Spacedman optimize in the sense of be more clean and readable.

Comment: @RafaelToledo suggest you edit your Q to make that clear. Cleanliness and readability of code is pretty subjective though...

Comment: ok, @Spacedman, pretty fair.

Comment: @BrodieG - I think that gives `2^data$x` not `data$x^2`

Comment: Ah, unfortunately you are correct, and given that is a primitive we have no recourse here :(.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(2:3, c("y", "z"), ~set_names(data_frame(data$x^.x), .y)) %>%
            bind_cols(data, .)   
#   x  y   z
#1: 1  1   1
#2: 2  4   8
#3: 3  9  27
#4: 4 16  64
#5: 5 25 125
#6: 6 36 216
#7: 7 49 343
#8: 8 64 512
#9: 9 81 729
```

---

Or we can remove the `data_frame` call

```
data %>%
     map2(2:3, ~ .^.y) %>%
     set_names(., c("y", "z")) %>%
     bind_cols(data, .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option following using `lapply`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:9)
df[c("y","z")] <- lapply(2:3, function(p) 
  df %>% 
    mutate(new = x^p) %>% 
    pull(new))
#   x  y   z
# 1 1  1   1
# 2 2  4   8
# 3 3  9  27
# 4 4 16  64
# 5 5 25 125
# 6 6 36 216
# 7 7 49 343
# 8 8 64 512
# 9 9 81 729
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative using only `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(!!!setNames(2:3, c("y", "z")),
         across(y:z, ~ x ^ .))
```

**Output**

```
      x     y     z
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     2     4     8
3     3     9    27
4     4    16    64
5     5    25   125
6     6    36   216
7     7    49   343
8     8    64   512
9     9    81   729
```

---

**How it works**

From `` ?rlang::`nse-force` `` :

> The big-bang operator !!! forces-splice a list of objects. The elements of the list are spliced in place, meaning that they each become one single argument.

To show you what the expression evaluates to use `rlang::qq_show`:

```
rlang::qq_show(mutate(!!!setNames(2:3, c("y", "z"))))

mutate(y = 2L, z = 3L)
```

Here you can see the names because the variable names and the elements become the variable values.

Then `across` iterates the function `x ^ .` over the specified variable range. The `.` is substituted with the current column iteration, `y` and then `z` in this case.